# Suggested Edit Rejection & Required Minimal Votes On Tag

Tags: discussion, tags, edits, rejected-edits

First things first,

I'm very confused to see my suggested edits https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14243921 rejected.

What I've done:

1. Removed multiple empty lines
2. Corrected indentation
3. Removed a single braceright, which was obviously a remnant of the class body

Overall the code was significantly easier to read, not least because the author used curly braces (like for [shadowing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4)) which wasn't obvious in the original post.

Additionally I would like to point out, that the three rejectors together have 2 votes on [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java).

Was it really necessary to reject the edits?

And if not (as I think), wouldn't it be nice to have some additional limitations, like minimal required votes on associated tags for edits and rejections?

Imao, there is a good reason why no-one should be able to touch, rate, edit or reject code of unfamiliar languages.

Comment: If I had to guess, at a glance, it might be because they saw a lot of red and green in the code and didn't realize that you'd only fixed the spacing to it's easier (at least in my mind) to read. As for needing minimal votes to approve or reject edits, most edits don't _need_ that. You're generally encouraged to only edit code to indent it, regardless of your tag score, just because you could end up fixing whatever the OP was asking about.

Comment: Many edits are simple grammar or formatting fixes that require knowledge in nothing more than the English language.

Comment: @TotZam Got it. What I'm asking about is just for code blocks. F.e. if I would try to fix Python, this would end up in a disaster, as indentation is part of the syntax here.

Comment: Also, although I see you were trying to make the if/else formatting consistent, personally, I like when if and else statements are each on their own line, so I actually find some of the code harder to read after your edit.

Comment: @TotZam good point, but it's not done without a reason, as there are at least some common [code conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-142311.html). Btw, that's exactly what I'm talking about. Had the same as a Java beginner, as I was used to write PHP code.

Comment: @Kendra actually no, we are encouraged to correct and update posts: ["to **correct minor mistakes** or add addendums / updates as the post ages"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing)

Comment: @Braiam If its just about code, isn't readable code suitable to "To clarify the meaning of the post". If I would change the code somehow, I might destroy the error / failure which the post is about. Imao Kendra was right.

Comment: But it's not a I-can-not-touch-code-with-a-10-ft-pole blanket statement. If you know the "mistake" wasn't intentional, ie. a stray } from copy-n-paste, you can correct it.

Comment: I guess my next question will be about un-commented down-votes. Is this discussion or the question really that bad?

Comment: @zyexal Yes, we are encouraged to make minor edits, but _editing code is usually a big no no_ because of what I stated earlier. See the FAQ post [When should I make edits to code?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code) for more information. Note that I don't think your edit is bad, I'm explaining why people may have not read further into your edit when they reviewed, and I may still not be correct for why they rejected. It's a guess.

Comment: @Kendra regarding to [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88627/how-far-can-i-refactor-the-code-in-someone-elses-question) I was totally right. But nvm, currently I'm more disappointed about the down-votes of this question ^^

Comment: Like I said, _I_ don't think your edit was bad. It made the code easier to read, imo. I was simply explaining that editing code can get your edit rejected fast if you actually change anything, or it looks like you did at a glance. As for the downvotes, it's probably because people do not feel your suggestion, that you need a certain tag score to review edits, is a good idea. Voting is like that on Meta, people vote on the proposal in posts _as well as_ quality.

Answer (score 10):

There's a problem with your edit. You use the single most common edit summary — "improved formatting" — which is all too often a code word for "derp derp derp imma make an edit derp herp". Sure, that's what you *did*, but how about being a little more specific? "Improved code indentation", for example. "Improved formatting" is never a good summary. And while the reviewers probably should have looked beyond the summary, it's not too surprising that they didn't.

This type of edit really isn't something that requires much experience with Java in particular to review accurately, just skill in reviewing (and a quick look at the stats of the reviewers isn't too impressive; only one of them has more than 250 reviews). Any C-family language uses very much the same indentation conventions, with a few exceptions (Go's enforced styleguide, etc). For that matter, even the functional and scripting languages *usually* don't have too much that can go wrong with whitespace, except Python's famous case. So requiring some complicated tag-score code-format-change suggested-edit review threshold just to maybe slightly improve a few reviews… it's not worth it.

Answer (score 4):

I would have preferred it if you didn't choose to edit *just* the code.  There's a contraction missing an apostrophe, for starters...

Given your reputation, your edits go into the port review queue, as you're well aware.  Edits that make it here should be substantive and not superfluous; despite the fact that no one likes to look at sloppy and poorly indented code, that's really not the kind of thing you should target in peer reviewed edits.

I personally would have rejected and improved such an edit as well for the reasons stated above.

Comment: Not Improve Edit?

Comment: @NathanTuggy: No, I'd reject then improve.  An edit that only fixes code and not grammar isn't deserving of the 2 rep it would otherwise get.